# How I may to render array of arrays in twig, Drupal 8?

Tags: arrays, drupal, twig, render

I have the following {{dump () }} output of my template, which has 'rows' variable which has array of arrays:

[Dump output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RN82b.png)

Question: How it's possible to render each array (ie feedback) in twig template?

Comment: I'd suggest to start by reading the [documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/templates.html#control-structure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be like this

```
{% for row in rows %}
    {{ row.feedback }}
{% endfor %}
```